# PostgreSQL: Add object to jsonb array by function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, element, jsonb

I'm having this `jsonb` array:
`[{"id": 1, "foo": false}, {"id": 1, "foo": true}]`

I have been struggling trying to add another field to all the objects inside. This is the result I'm looking for:

`[{"id": 1, "foo": false, "bar": true}, {"id": 1, "foo": true, "bar": true}]`

I know I need to write a function but I'm kind of new to PostgreSQL so I'm not sure where to start. This is the closest thread I can find: [Postgres/JSON - update all array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276968/postgres-json-update-all-array-elements) but they're to update an existing object by the key.

Any help or point to the direction is much appreciated.

Edit:

I tried to modified to this function

```
create or replace function add_elements(arr jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object("bar", true))
    from jsonb_array_elements(arr) e(e)    
$$;
```

but PostgreSQL complained about `ERROR:  column "bar" does not exist`

I'm using Postgres 9.5

Comment: What version of postgres are you targeting?

Comment: @teppic Sorry, forgot to add, I'm using Postgres 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator on elements got from `jsonb_array_elements()`:

```
with my_table(arr) as (
values
    ('[{"id": 1, "foo": false}, {"id": 1, "foo": true}]'::jsonb)
)

select jsonb_agg(elem || '{"bar": true}'::jsonb)
from my_table,
jsonb_array_elements(arr) elem;

                                  jsonb_agg                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id": 1, "bar": true, "foo": false}, {"id": 1, "bar": true, "foo": true}]
(1 row)
```

Your function may look like this:

```
create or replace function add_elements(arr jsonb, val jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select jsonb_agg(elem || val)
    from jsonb_array_elements(arr) elem    
$$;


with my_table(arr) as (
values
    ('[{"id": 1, "foo": false}, {"id": 1, "foo": true}]'::jsonb)
)

select add_elements(arr, '{"bar": true}')
from my_table;

                                add_elements                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id": 1, "bar": true, "foo": false}, {"id": 1, "bar": true, "foo": true}]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Nicely done, it works! I've been coming close but never used json_agg before so it was quite confusing. Thank you very much!