# How To Merge Multiple PostgreSQL JSON Arrays That Are The Result Of Another JSON Array Update On All Of Its Elements?

Tags: json, postgresql, union, postgresql-json

Given the following two table columns `jsonb` type:

**dividend_actual**

```
{
  "dividends": [
    {
      "amount": "2.9800",
      "balanceDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "amount": "4.3100",
      "balanceDate": "2019-06-30T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ],
  "lastUpdated": "2020-11-16T14:50:51.289649512Z",
  "providerUpdateDate": "2020-11-16T00:00:00Z"
}
```

**dividend_forecast**

```
{
  "dividends": [
    {
      "amount": "2.3035",
      "balanceDate": "2021-06-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "amount": "3.0452",
      "balanceDate": "2022-06-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      "amount": "3.1845",
      "balanceDate": "2023-06-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ],
  "lastForecasted": "2020-11-13T00:00:00Z",
  "providerUpdateDate": "2020-11-16T00:00:00Z"
}
```

I would like to merge both `dividends` arrays from `dividend_actual` and `dividend_forecast`, but before merging them I want to add an extra field (`forecast`) on every single object.

I did try the following:

```
SELECT
    dividends
FROM
    stock_financial AS f
    INNER JOIN instrument AS i ON i.id = f.instrument_id,
    jsonb_array_elements(
        (f.dividend_forecast->'dividends' || jsonb '{"forecast": true}') || 
        (f.dividend_actual->'dividends' || jsonb '{"forecast": false}')
    ) AS dividends
WHERE
    i.symbol = 'ASX_CBA'
ORDER BY
    dividends ->>'balanceDate' DESC;
```

The above query gives me the following results:

```
{"forecast":true}
{"forecast":false}
{"amount":"3.1845","balanceDate":"2023-06-01T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"3.0452","balanceDate":"2022-06-01T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"2.3035","balanceDate":"2021-06-01T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"2.9800","balanceDate":"2020-06-30T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"4.3100","balanceDate":"2019-06-30T00:00:00Z"}
```

But what I need instead is the following output:

```
{"amount":"3.1845","balanceDate":"2023-06-01T00:00:00Z","forecast":true}
{"amount":"3.0452","balanceDate":"2022-06-01T00:00:00Z","forecast":true}
{"amount":"2.3035","balanceDate":"2021-06-01T00:00:00Z","forecast":true}
{"amount":"2.9800","balanceDate":"2020-06-30T00:00:00Z","forecast":false}
{"amount":"4.3100","balanceDate":"2019-06-30T00:00:00Z","forecast":false}
```

Comment: Could you provide some example input data.

Comment: Sure, no worries added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it is not possible to update multiple jsons objects within a json array in a single operation by default.

To be able to do that a `Postgres function` needs to be created:

```
-- the params are the same as in aforementioned `jsonb_set`
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_json_array_elements(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb language sql AS $$
    -- aggregate the jsonb from parts created in LATERAL
    SELECT jsonb_agg(updated_jsonb)
    -- split the target array to individual objects...
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(target) individual_object,
    -- operate on each object and apply jsonb_set to it. The results are aggregated in SELECT
    LATERAL jsonb_set(individual_object, path, new_value) updated_jsonb
  $$;
```

The above function was suggested by [kubak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185621/kubak) in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53712268/782390

Combined with this query:

```
SELECT
    dividends
FROM
    stock_financial AS f
    INNER JOIN instrument AS i ON i.id = f.instrument_id,
    jsonb_array_elements(
        update_json_array_elements(f.dividend_forecast->'dividends', '{forecast}', 'true') ||
        update_json_array_elements(f.dividend_actual->'dividends', '{forecast}', 'false')
    ) AS dividends
WHERE
    i.symbol = 'ASX_CBA'
ORDER BY
    dividends ->>'balanceDate' DESC;
```

I then get the following output, that it is exactly what I need:

```
{"amount":"3.1845","forecast":true,"balanceDate":"2023-06-01T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"3.0452","forecast":true,"balanceDate":"2022-06-01T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"2.3035","forecast":true,"balanceDate":"2021-06-01T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"2.9800","forecast":false,"balanceDate":"2020-06-30T00:00:00Z"}
{"amount":"4.3100","forecast":false,"balanceDate":"2019-06-30T00:00:00Z"}
```